# Server 2012 Profiles not saving (marked as temp)

Tags: windows-server-2012, user-profile

I have a Windows Server 2012 machine that randomly starting today wiped a user's profile and now will not save any changes after he logs out (desktop icons, bookmarks, etc.).  His machine does this for all users including mine (a Domain admin) and the local admin account.  I've tried deleting the profile folders as well as the matching entries in registry profile list.  The newly created profiles are also marked as temp and won't save any information.  There is no registry entry causing this and none of the other machines in the domain have this issue.  This even happened with a freshly created domain user account.  No idea what caused this or how to fix, please help.

Comment: Please add some error you see in your eventlog related to the profile loading.

Comment: No relevant errors in the event logs.  The profiles are listed as temporary so I guess it is working as it's meant to but I can't change them to local profiles and I'm not sure why they are being automatically set as temporary.

Like I said, no other domain machine is acting this way so it isn't a group policy setting and it does this for any account, even freshly created ones.

Comment: If someone, like the group everyone is in the group guest that would happen. (check the local goup guest, it should be empty)

Comment: That was it!  Thanks bunches.  Not sure who or how the everyone group got added to the guest group but removing it fixed the issue.

Comment: Perfect :) I will write it as an answer then if it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please verify the local group 'guest', any member of it will receive a temporary profile.